# Atlassian Bamboo - Determine Which Agent is Available to Run Plan

Tags: bamboo

I don't know if what I am trying to do is even possible or not, but hopefully I can get some answers here.

We have 5 agents (1 local, 4 remote) and basically what we would like to do is, determine which of the 4 remote agents are currently NOT being used/building a plan and then use that agent to perform a build.

What I have currently done is dedicated 1 remote agent to perform the required build, but ideally what we would like to do is build the plan on whichever agent is available - so as to not dedicate agents for specific plans.

Getting Bamboo up and running has been a massive headache because frankly, the documentation and support on basic tasks are either overwhelming and confusing or non-existent - Not to mention, outdated?

Answer (score 0):

Bamboo by design checks capabilities of existing agents and then assign build to any available one. You don't need to use "dedicate agent" feature except special cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can add *Shared remote capabilities* which will be inherited by all remote agents, and use that as the requirement for you job.

Access it under *Bamboo administration* -> *Agents* -> *Shared remote capabilities*, or using the URL path directly `/bamboo/admin/agent/configureSharedRemoteCapabilities.action`.

[image: Configure bamboo agents]